# Disable Google Chrome zoom popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a little extensions for zooming pages without keyboard (chrome is running in kiosk mode)

But whenever users zoom the page, this popup comes out :

[image]

Is there any way I can disable this beahoviour?

Because when user clicks on the extension symbol the extensions page appears and this ruins the kiosk experience

Comment: How do you zoom the page? The popup won't show if you use something like `document.body.style.zoom = '200%'`

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-setZoom this is what I am using. I think it has less chance to 'break' pages than setting zoom to body directly

Comment: I have exactly the same problem to solve.  Did anyone ever figure out how to use setZoom() without the zoom dialog temporarily showing up?

Comment: There must be a solution to that, since the "zoom-for-google-chrome" extension does not show the native zoom popup.
Maybe that is only in "CSS-Mode" of the extension, as stated here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/zoom-level-popping-up-as-each-page-loads/9fd66d27-cf2d-42dc-a540-381f8c579c03